# np transpose and squeeze have no effect

Tags: image, numpy

I load (an) image(s) via

```
batches =datagen.flow_from_directory(...)
```

I want to plot a sample image to see the augmentations by the datagnerator.

```
display(img_batch[0].shape)
```

shows me (1, 256, 256, 3)

Then I transpose

```
image = img_batch[i].transpose((2,1,3,0))
```

Here the first "error" happens. Usually I would transpose to

```
image = img_batch[i].transpose((2,1,3))
```

but then I get an error

> ValueError: axes don't match array

So I transpose as shown and get

> (256, 256, 3, 1)

So I think, np.squeez could solve this, but when I use any variation of

```
np.squeeze(image,(3,))
```

just nothing happens, shape before and after show the same.

I have no clue what happens. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks

Comment: It works for me, shape is (256, 256, 3) after `np.squeeze(image,(3,))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the output of `np.squeeze(image,(3,))` to a variable, it does not do in-place changes to the variable.

`image = np.squeeze(image,(3,))`

Then `image.shape` will return `(256, 256, 3)`

As a side note, you can call `squeeze` without specifying `axis` in your case as the function will by default remove dimensions of length 1.

**Edit about the use of transposition:**

In numpy, the `transpose` function expects `axis` to be a tuple of same dimension as the number of dimensions of the array you transpose.

In your case `image` is a 4-dimensional array (as you transpose it before squeezing it), therefore, when you call `transpose` with `axis=(2, 1, 3)` it will raise a `ValueError`. Calling it with a 4-dimensional tuple argument works as expected.

If you squeeze before transposing, then you can call transpose with `axis` being a 3-dimensional tuple.

Comment: Cheers. How stupid of me. To my excuse, it was a long day :-). But one question, should it not also have worked with the transpose? Do you know why that did not work? Thanks

Comment: @FloridaMan I added details about the transpose to my answer. Also, there is no stupid question ;)